Convergence or divergence of series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} (\ln{n})^x$
Recently I'm reading K. F. Riley's book "Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering", I can't solve exercise 4.11(6) at page 145, and the solution/answer puzzles me.
Question:
Find the real value of $x$ for which the following series are convergent:
$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} (\ln{n})^x$
Hints from the book itself:
Always divergent. Clearly divergent for $x > -1$. For $-X = x < -1$, consider
$$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{n = M_{k-1}+1}^{M_k}\frac{1}{(\ln M_k)^X} $$
where $\ln M_k = k$ and note that $M_k - M_{k-1} = e^{-1}(e-1)M_k$; hence show that the series diverges.
Answer from the student's solution, saying that:
The sum $S=\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}(\ln n)^x$ is clearly divergent for all $x>-1$ (by comparison with $\sum n^{-1}$). So we define a positive $X$ by $-X = x<-1$ and consider
$$S_1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{r_k = M_{k-1}+1}^{M_k}\frac{1}{(\ln M_k)^X} $$,where $M_k$ is the lowest integer such that $\ln M_k > k$. The notation is such that when $e^{k-1}<n<e^k$, then $n = M_{k-1} + r_k$.
For each fixed $k$, every term in the second (finite) summation is smaller than the corresponding term in $S$ (because $n<M_k$). But, since all the terms in such a summation are equal, the value of the sum is simply $(M_k - M_{k-1})/(\ln M_k)^X$. Thus
$$S_1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{M_k-M_{k-1}}{(\ln M_k)^X}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-1})M_k}{(\ln M_k)^X}$$.
Now the ratio of successive terms in this final summation is
$$\frac{M_{k+1}}{(\ln M_{k+1})^X}\frac{(\ln M_k)^X}{M_k}\rightarrow\frac{e}{\ln e} $$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.
This limit is $>1$, and thus $S_1$ diverges for all $X$; hence, by the comparison test, so does $S$.
My understanding of the answer:
As $e^n = 1 + n + ... > n$, this leads to $\ln n<n$ or $\frac{1}{\ln n}>\frac{1}{n}$, we know the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, so as series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\ln n}}$. Which means for all $x\ge -1$ (not only $x>-1$ as mentioned in the answer), the series is divergent.
Now follow the answer, if we define $M_k$ as the lowest integer of  $\ln M_k > k$ or $M_k > e^k$, which means $M_k - 1 < e^k$, and similarly $M_{k-1} > e^{k-1}$ and $M_{k-1} - 1 < e^{k-1}$.
Here the answer seems to define $n$ as all possible integers between $e^{k-1}$ and $e^k$, or $e^{k-1} < n < e^{k}$. From above, we know
$$M_{k-1}-1<e^{k-1}<n<e^{k}<M_k$$
which means
$$M_{k-1}\le n \le M_k-1$$
By this way if $n=M_{k-1} + r_k$, the possible integers of $r_k$ is from $0$ to $M_k -M_{k-1} - 1$, it has $M_k - M_{k-1}$ numbers.
The $hints$ seems to use $n$ while the $answer$ use $r_k$ to repeat calculating $1/(\ln M_k)^X$.
I guess this explains the numerator of the second equation of $S_1$, however, I don't understand how it leads to $M_k - M_{k-1} = (1-e^{-1})M_k$ for $S_1$, the former is still an integer, while the latter isn't.
I don't understand how the final summation comes close to $e/\ln e$ either, if $M_{k+1} = eM_k$ maybe yes, but how could it be possible as any $M_k$ is an integer and $e$ is an irrational number?
Thanks for any help.

you may wish to consider the integral series test for the case $x<-1$

(as an alternative solution)

The sum of $1/n$ is divergent, not convergent in your understanding.

You are right, I made a typo, I have corrected it, thanks for pointing it out.

The equation for $S_1$ should probably be $S_1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{M_k-M_{k-1}}{(\ln M_k)^X}\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-1})M_k}{(\ln M_k)^X}$

I agree, but how to prove this? I assume we should prove $eM_{k-1} > M_k$, but I really don't know how to get this. From above, it seems only that $eM_{k-1} > e^k$ and $M_k > e^k$.

I agree with Wei's answer, it's not well demonstrated that $M_k/M_{k-1}\to e^-$. It's much more straightforward to consider $\int_2^{\infty}{\frac{dt}{(\ln{t})^x}}$, which diverges for all $x$

This is not an answer. Just an extended comment that's tangentially related to the question.
For those that are curious while this sum is ALWAYS divergent it can also always be assigned a divergent renormalization.
Recall that
$$\zeta(s) = 1 + 2^{-s} + 3^{-s} + ... = 1 + e^{-s\ln(2)} + e^{-s\ln(3)} ... $$
Therefore
$$ \frac{d^Q}{ds^Q} \left[\zeta(-s) \right] = 0 + \ln(2)^Qe^{s\ln(2)} + \ln(3)^Q e^{s\ln(3)} + ... $$
If $Q>0$ and taken to be the fractional derivative. Evaluating at $s=0$ we then have:
$$ \frac{d^Q}{ds^Q} \left[\zeta(-s) \right]_{@s=0} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ln(n)^Q$$
So for example we can find that
$$ \frac{d^1}{ds^1} \left[ \zeta(-s) \right]_{@s=0} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ln(n) = \frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi)$$
In a way very analogous to the fact that
$$ \zeta(-1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n = -\frac{1}{12} $$
The case of $Q \le 0$ is a little trickier to implement since these become fractional "integrals" and without carefully selecting bounds you can end up with ANY answer. Now while this can be done, a safer approach is to just define $\zeta_2(Q) = \frac{d^Q}{ds^Q} \left[ \zeta(-s) \right]_{@s=0}$ and then analytically continue it into the negative real half of the complex plane.

The proof writer seems to be playing fast and loose with the value of the $M_k$, suggesting that $M_k$ is an integer close enough to $e^k$ that it can be considered equal when it's convenient to do so. And you are right to be a bit dubious about this - I would also prefer a bit more rigour in the argument. If you wanted to use the same proof method more rigorously, you could instead define $M_k=2^k$ and follow the same steps, only this time the $M_k$ would be genuine integers and the proof would work without hand-waving.
Or if you're happy to consider an alternative proof method, for $x<0$ the assumptions of the Cauchy condensation test apply.

Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if I correctly understand your method, I tried:
$$ S_1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{n = M_{k-1}+1}^{M_k}\frac{1}{(\ln M_k)^X} $$
This time, let $M_k = 2^k$ and $M_{k-1}=2^{k-1}$ and etc. As $n$ counts  $M_k - M_{k-1} = 2^{k-1}$ times, so that
$$ S_1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k-1}}{(\ln M_k)^X} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k-1}}{(\ln 2^k)^X} $$
According to Cauchy condensation test
$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}2^nf(2^n) \ge \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n) $$

So we have:
$$  S_1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k-1}}{(\ln 2^k)^X} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}}{(\ln 2^{n+1})^X} \ge \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln 2n)^X} $$
The left work would be to prove as Barri comments to consider
$$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(\ln 2t)^X} $$
to be diverges for all $X$ ?
BTW, during the process, how we prove $S_1 > S$  ?

$S_1 \leq S$ by pointwise comparison just as in the original proof. And $$S_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{(n+1)^X(\ln2)^X}$$ which diverges (exponentials increase faster than any polynomial).
